# Apex Test in VS Code: "Faye client generated a transport:down event"

Tags: apex, unit-test, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

Weird message when I tried to use Salesforce Extensions to run an Apex test in VS Code this morning:

```
Running SFDX: Run Apex Tests: Faye client generated a transport:down event.
```

[image]

Who is Faye, and where is she trying to take me?

Or in all seriousness: I do understand this has [may have something to do with a network issue](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000JfQDTSA3). However, I don't have a problem using the CLI directly in Git Bash. These both work:

```
sf apex run test --class-names "MyTest" --result-format human
```

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run -n "MyTest" -r human
```

Deploying code to my sandbox using Salesforce Extensions also works.

- SFDX version: `sfdx-cli/7.194.1 win32-x64 node-v18.15.0`
- Salesforce Extension Pack version: `v57.10.2`

This wasn't happening Friday -- could it have something to do with Summer '23 going live in preview sandboxes? Maybe something to do with auto-enablement of Enhanced Domains? I tried re-authorizing the org, but it didn't help.

Ultimately: how can I resolve this?

Comment: Well, I don't think this qualifies as an answer, but I feel obligated to post this nonetheless. When I tried running tests again this morning, the problem had automagically resolved itself. So, yay! And for those who trip across this in the future: sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was trying to replicate this error but couldn't. It does seem like a network issue.